# Jupyter Notebook Hide DB Connection Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science

How I hidden informations secrets like connection DB or Parameter Plotly in Jupyter Notebook?

I´m think in create json file out folder Jupyter and access with path using ../ 
Someone have other option?

Comment: Who do you want to hide it from?

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to hide the code cells. [Here is a Jupyter notebook extension](https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code) for hiding code cells. If you only would like to share the results of your work, I guess after setting your DB connection/parameter you can just delete the cell that contains the sensitive information.